# How do I obtain the Nightingale Armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have seen this armor in Skyrim around the internet, and I have no idea how to get it. I think it may have something to do with Thieves Guild, but I don't know any more. How do I get this armor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_Armor):

> ## Acquisition
>
> The full set is given to the Dragonborn by [Karliah](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Karliah) before performing
> the initiation ritual of the [Nightingales](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_%28Skyrim%29) during the quest "[Trinity
> Restored](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity_Restored_%28Quest%29)" for the [Thieves Guild](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_%28Skyrim%29). All pieces are obtained when
> activating the Armor Stone, emblazoned with the Nightingales symbol,
> inside [Nightingale Hall](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_Hall).

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is from an official source...

Comment: Official? The Elder Scrolls Wikia is as far from official as it comes.

Comment: @BillyMailman Really? Why do you say that?  It was more concise than your answer was, and I can verify it is correct from gameplay.

Comment: @syb0rg UESP is the accepted source: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Armor

Comment: @Vaishali That was exactly my thoughts...

Comment: @Vaishali But I said accepted, as in the community, as far as I can tell, treats UESP as a 'better' source.

Comment: Well this answer sparked an argument

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that you will need to join the [Thieves Guild](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)). After running through the Guild's main questline, you will reach the quest [Trinity Restored](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Trinity_Restored), in which your character is invited to join the Nightingales. The armour will be provided free as part of the initiation ceremony.

Answer (score -2):

unlock "perfect touch" perk in pickpocketing skill tree. Join the thieves guild until you reach "trinity restored" quest line. After finishing the quest, sneak and pickpocket karliah and get all of her nightingale equipments.

Comment: Or you could just take the set you are given during that same quest. Much easier than stealing it from a master thief.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you need to do some thief questline quests, you'll meet Karliah in some of these quests, make sure to do they and she'll make you become a Nightingale!

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said.  Do you have anything to add beyond what other answerers have stated?

Comment: Hamarok was just trying to help